# is there a generic import path in golang?

Tags: go

Consider a go code show below where it uses v3 in the import path. Now at somepoint when i want to go for a newer version, say v4, i'm updating import path in all my library codes

```
import "google.golang.org/api/youtube/v3"

youtubeService, err := youtube.New(oauthHttpClient)
```

Is there a way to do this better? say import latest and latest refers to v4?

Comment: No.  But search and replace is pretty easy.

Comment: But note that using "latest" is pretty universally a bad idea. That leads to completely unpredictable, and non-reproducible builds.

Answer (score 0):

> []Is there a generic import path in [] Go?
> Is there a way to do this better? say import latest and latest refers to v4?

No, no and no.

According to semver v3 and v4 are basically *different* packages. v4 can have arbitrary large incompatibilities against v3. The idea of importing "latests" thus makes no sense given the major version of Go packages should conform to semantic versioning.